# Heap Based Overflow

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, heap-memory, buffer-overflow

I am writing a file upload service using a remote procedure call(gRPC) in C++. The Client splits a file into chunks and sends the chunks over the gRPC stream. The server reads off the gRPC stream and writes to a file. There is heap based overflow when I read off the gRPC stream. I solved this using strcpy, but using strcpy pollutes my file. How do I resolve the heap based overflow

Proto object

```
    message FileContent {
  bytes content = 1;
  int32 counter = 2;
}
```

Client Writer

```
char buffer[4096];
 while(file_offset < filelength)
 {
    memset(buffer,0,4096);
    bytes_read = pread(filedes, buffer, 4096,file_offset);
    filecontent.set_content(std::string(buffer, bytes_read));
    filecontent.set_counter(bytes_read);
    writer->Write(filecontent);
    file_offset+=bytes_read;
  }
```

Server Reader

```
char buffer[4096];
  while (reader->Read(&filecontent))
   {
     bytes_read=filecontent.counter();
     cout << "Bytes Read" << bytes_read << endl;
     strcpy(buffer,filecontent.mutable_content()->c_str());  // if I don't do this, I get heap based overflow when the next line executes. But this corrupts my file. How do I fix it?
     write(filedes, buffer,(bytes_read));
     file_offset+=bytes_read;
   }
```

I am reading file data from a continuous stream. The file is split into chunks and sent on a gRPC stream. Each chunk needs condition at the server side with a strcpy operation to prevent heap based overflow, but if I do this, I am corrupting file bytes. How do I read from the stream and write to a file without adding a null terminator. PLEASE HELP!!!

Answer (score 2):

Your grpc filecontent member should have a `copy()` function. Instead of using `strcpy`, you could copy the file content using this function:

`filecontent.content().copy(buffer,bytes_read)`